# django haystack 2.0 contains query

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

Even though doc says
`The contains filter became the new default filter as of Haystack v2.X (the default in Haystack v1.X was exact). This changed because exact caused problems and was unintuitive for new people trying to use Haystack. contains is a much more natural usage.` http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html

I find my Solr returns `exact` match.

I tried subclassing SearchForm and overriding `search` function to use
filter(content__contains=...) as suggested by [django haystack how do I find substrings in words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987177/django-haystack-how-do-i-find-substrings-in-words)
But it doesn't work.

How do I do the `contains` search?
Using Ngram suggested in [Django-Haystack with Solr contains search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337811/django-haystack-with-solr-contains-search) is the only way to do it?

I'm using solr 3.6 if that matters.

Comment: solution posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33260538/333566